# What does the numbers in Java printf() mean?

Tags: java, string-formatting

When I see this in java, I know that the .2 is the decimal place, f is for float, n is for newline, etc. But what is the 6?

```
System.out.printf("%6.2f2%n", someDouble);
```

Comment: What part of the Javadoc didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stands for the length of the string that is returned by the printf method.
So in this case a string that is at least 6 characters long.

Which means that if

```
someDouble=pi
```

then

```
System.out.printf("%6.2f2%n", someDouble);
```

will print out the string

```
"  3.14"
```

(i.e. 2 whitespaces followed by 4 characters containing 3.14)

Another example would be

```
System.out.printf("%2.2f2%n", someDouble);
```

Which prints out

```
"3.14"
```

We can see from this that this does not override the `.2` or anything else in this command if a shorter value is given than is needed for other rules to apply.

So this only makes sure there is extra whitespace preceding the value.

Comment: What does the "6 characters in width" mean? Does that mean it's limiting something?

Comment: It means that the string that is returned is 6 characters in length

Comment: You can also write 06, then it will be left-filled with zeros.

Comment: Just so you know: To have formatted blocks of code, indent the code lines by 4 spaces (Easiest way to do that is to paste in the code, select it and press Ctrl+K). If you want in-line code, enclose it with `\`backticks\``.